# Flume gives an error

Tags: hadoop

Can someone help me on this. I am running a flume agent. After running it gives me an exception as below.

> Disk quota exceeded (122) at
>   com.mapr.fs.MapRClientImpl.create(MapRClientImpl.java:159) at
>   com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.create(MapRFileSystem.java:640) at
>   com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.create(MapRFileSystem.java:682) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:809) at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSDataStream.doOpen(HDFSDataStream.java:86)
>   at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSDataStream.open(HDFSDataStream.java:113)
>   at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:275)
>   at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:720)
>   at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.runPrivileged(BucketWriter.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.access$1700(BucketWriter.java:59)
>   at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:717)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: The very first line is `Disk quota exceeded`.

Comment: Can you please let me know what you mean here?

Comment: It means that you've run out of disk space.

Comment: When I check disk space, I see its 98% empty.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can say. The code that you're running on your computer is telling you that there's not enough space. Check the quota for the user it's running as, and make sure there's enough.

Comment: Let me change the user disk quota to some more spaces and let me run again